# Parsing cbor stream

Tags: parsing, containers, decoding, cbor

I'm trying to parse CBOR stream using tinyCBOR. Goal is to write a generic parsing code for "**map type**"(because i don't know how many keys are there and which are they, in cbor stream)but not for a json, I just want to get values using "**key**",but for getting values from key i have to know the key. 
Im simply able to parse the value by passing "**key**" in function

```
cbor_value_map_find_value(&main_value,"Age",&map_value);
```

but few things still not clear to me.

What sequence to follow, for getting key and values from CBOR stream?

For eg. following is my data in map format -

```
{"Roll_number": 7, "Age": 24, "Name": "USER"}
```

here is this binary format from cbor.me link -

```
   A3                        # map(3)
   6B                        # text(11)
   526F6C6C5F6E756D626572    # "Roll_number"
   07                        # unsigned(7)
   63                        # text(3)
   416765                    # "Age"
   18 18                     # unsigned(24)
   64                        # text(4)
   4E616D65                  # "Name"
   64                        # text(4)
   55534552                  # "USER"
```

1.How to get key from stream. like - Roll_number or AGE from stream?(sequentially getting key and values also fine).

2.After getting Roll_number value, how can i jump to next element ("**Age**") for getting "**key**" and "**value**".

3.How to identify that i'm reached at the "**end of stream**" and now there is no data ??

Any snippet code, that how to parse and which sequence of function need to follow.

Any help is appreciate.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The [example code](https://github.com/intel/tinycbor/blob/main/examples/simplereader.c) is pretty helpful for understanding the API.  To iterate over the keys and values of a map, you call [`cbor_value_enter_container`](https://intel.github.io/tinycbor/current/a00047.html#ga0c8a61e484973272f34b00cfbef9ddfd), then [`cbor_value_advance`](https://intel.github.io/tinycbor/current/a00047.html#gae2ede5aacd59f04437c24ef8ca2f449a) until [`cbor_value_at_end`](https://intel.github.io/tinycbor/current/a00047.html#ga49bd2a99edcceb72962eedc7584cd19c) returns true (as long as there are no nested maps or arrays you want to look inside).  For example:

```c
cbor_parser_init(input, sizeof(input), 0, &parser, &it);
if (!cbor_value_is_map(&it)) {
  return 1;
}
err = cbor_value_enter_container(&it, &map);
if (err) return 1;
while (!cbor_value_at_end(&map)) {
  // get the key.  Remember, keys don't have to be strings.
  if (!cbor_value_is_text_string(&map)) {
    return 1;
  }
  char *buf;
  size_t n;
  // Note: this also advances to the value
  err = cbor_value_dup_text_string(&map, &buf, &n, &map);
  if (err) return 1;
  printf("Key: '%*s'\n", (int)n-1, buf);

  if (strncmp(buf, "Age", n-1) == 0) {
    if (cbor_value_is_integer(&map)) {
      // Found the expected key and value type
      err = cbor_value_get_int(&map, &val);
      if (err) return 1;
      printf("age: %d\n", val);
    }
    // note: can't break here, have to keep going until the end if you want
    // `it` to still be valid.
  }
  free(buf);
  err = cbor_value_advance(&map);
  if (err) return 1;
}
err = cbor_value_leave_container(&it, &map);
if (err) return 1;
```